# Eigenstate function for zero potential

Tags: homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

For a particle whose potential is zero, which means $V(x)=0$, how to solve the Schroedinger equation $$\frac{-h^2}{2m}\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \psi(x)=E\psi$$ to get the eigenfunction $e^{ikx}$?

If I use $ih\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$ as my energy operator, clearly $e^{ikx}$ is not the solution.

Comment: Try $e^{i(\omega t + kx)}$

Answer (score 1):

The time-independent Schrödinger equation is $\frac{-\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\psi(x)=E\psi(x)$ in the absence of a potential. $e^{\mathrm{i}kx}$ is indeed a solution to that for some $k$.

Comment: So the next step should be substituting Eψ(x)  as an coeffieient e times ψ(x)  and then to solve a simple differential equation, right?